# Why I can't read the ResponseHeaders of this downloaded page with WebClient?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, webclient

This is the page I want to analize (which is **iso-8859-1**):

```
http://www.unione.tn.it/cms-01.00/articolo.asp?IDcms=20488
```

So if you look at the source code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

This is my code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent);
    var rawBytes = client.DownloadData(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(resoruce_url));

    var contentType = new ContentType(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"]);
    Response.Write(client.ResponseHeaders);
}
```

but it prints:

```
Content-Length: 22967 
Content-Type: text/html 
Date: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 14:24:17 GMT Expires: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 14:24:16 GMT 
Set-Cookie: Lang=1; expires=Fri, 16-Jan-2015 23:00:00 GMT; path=/,ASPSESSIONIDACCAQTTC=PGGNBKJAHLBBCMELCOMHMHJG; path=/ 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0 
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 
Cache-control: private
```

`Content-Type` is `text/html`. It has lost **iso-8859-1**.

Why? And how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get charset value (page encoding) you could try this

```
Encoding encoding = null;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString(websiteUrl);
    encoding = doc.DetectEncodingHtml(html);
}
```